# An inconsistency with SQL in ORACLE

Tags: java, sql, oracle, toad

When I do the following query I get this error message:
**ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-01722: invalid number**

The query is

```
select l.LanguageName as language 
from mpi_provider.mpiprovider m, mpi_provider.provlanguage l 
where m.providerid = l.providerattestid and m.npi = 1548204944
```

I thought maybe it was just too high of a number, but when I use both/either
**m.npi = 1548204943** or **m.npi = 1548204945** the query works fine (though there are no records found).  If I add another digit, **m.npi = 15482049449**, it works fine as well as if I cut off a digit.

I can't figure out what is going on.  Any ideas?
npi is defined as Number(10) and can be null

Comment: Please show the `create table` statements for the two tables.

Comment: How can npi hold an eleven digit number when it is defined as NUMBER(10)? It works with 10 digit numbers, which is the limit.

Comment: Maybe it's because `15482049449` is out of range for the column (which is defined as NUMBER(10), but 15482049449 is eleven digits long).

Comment: Is there a `UNIQUE` constraint?

Comment: It's very possible that the error is in this clause `where m.providerid = l.providerattestid` and not the clause related to NPI. If `m.providerid` is a CHAR type, and `l.providerattestid` is not, then it will work for certain values of `m.npi` as long as `m.providerid` can be converted to a NUMBER

Comment: The error indicates at least one of the tables is an external table.  So this could be related to the data in the underlying external files.  Quite simply we cannot answer this question on the info you have given so far.  You need to provide the definitions of the two tables.  Also sample data for both cases: when the query completes and when it fails.

Comment: OK Thanks.  I just fear that before I can show more I'd better get an OK from the company as it may be confidential.  I will look at response #5 though.  They are the same thing so they should be the same dataa type but maybe they are not.  Thanks